# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject,

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am using a tab bar view in a flexible, which is inside a column. As a result, I am getting the incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

Here's the code to my body:

```
Widget _buildBody() {
    TabController _topTabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this, animationDuration: Duration.zero);
    var loc = Utils.getLocalizations(context)!;
    double deviceWidth = Utils.deviceWidth(context);

  
    _topTabController.animateTo(tabIndex);

    _topTabController.addListener(() {
      if (!_topTabController.indexIsChanging) {
        tabIndex = _topTabController.index;
      }
    });

    //this gesture detector ensures that the search bar loses focus when an empty space on the screen is tapped
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            HomePageBanner(title: loc.messagesTitle,),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  //This is for bottom border that is needed
                  border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300, width: 0.8)),
                ),
                child: TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                  labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                  unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                  controller: _topTabController,
                  indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 3.0),
                  ),
                  tabs: [
                    Tab( text: loc.messagesJustMetTabName,),
                    Tab(text: loc.messagesFriendsTabName,)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: deviceWidth*0.012, right: deviceWidth*0.012, top: 5),
                child: TabBarView(
                  controller: _topTabController,
                  children: [
                    StatefulBuilder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context, void Function(void Function()) setMetState) {
                        return _justMetTab(context, setMetState);
                      },
                    ),
                    StatefulBuilder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context, void Function(void Function()) setFriendState) {
                        return _friendsTab(context, setFriendState);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have tried wrapping the column in a sized box and giving it a fixed height, but this just makes every widget on the screen disappear. I have also tried wrapping the sized bar itself in a sized box, but all the widgets disappear as well.

Here's an example of the what the page looks like for better understanding:
[image: Screen]

It all looks good now, but when I run the app in test flight, I get a grey screen because of the ParentDataWidgetError.

**EDIT:**
I have added the body() method here for context on where _buildBody() is located in the widget tree:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
      future: getAllChatRequests(), // async work
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
            } else {
              return _buildBody();
            }
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

**EDIT:**

Also adding the error log here for more context:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a RepaintBoundary widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  Padding ← Expanded ← StatefulBuilder ← KeyedSubtree-[<0>] ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree-[Key <[<0>]>] ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5960:11)
#1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5977:6)
#2      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5999:7)
#3      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5673:5)
#4      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6214:11)
...     Normal element mounting (53 frames)
#57     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:16)
#58     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#59     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1265:37)
#60     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1250:20)
#61     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2597:19)
#62     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1242:12)
#63     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:349:23)
#64     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2025:59)
#65     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:918:15)
#66     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2025:14)
#67     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:338:5)
#68     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:422:5)
#69     RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart:205:12)
#70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#71     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
#72     _RenderSliverFractionalPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver_fill.dart:167:11)
#73     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#74     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
#75     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1580:12)
#76     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1489:20)
#77     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#78     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#79     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#80     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#81     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#82     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#83     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#84     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#85     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#86     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#87     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#88     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#89     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#90     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:233:12)
#91     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#92     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#93     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:896:45)
#94     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#95     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#96     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#97     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#98     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#99     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1376:11)
#100    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#101    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#102    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#103    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#104    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1915:7)
#105    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#106    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1757:7)
#107    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
#108    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:504:19)
#109    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:892:13)
#110    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
#111    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
#112    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
#113    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:997:5)
#117    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#118    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#119    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the flexible widget here.. please remove the flexible. Or if you wish to keep it wrap the column with a sized box of size same as device and use expanded in place of flexible.

Comment: When I remove the flexible widget, the whole page goes blank and I get this error: "Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height."..."RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#4a04f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'"

Comment: Wrap the column with sized box same as the device

Comment: The height or the width? or both?

Comment: Both height and width

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't work. Still the same error

Comment: Where is _buildbody added in the widget tree?

Comment: I added it as an edit in the post!

Comment: Can you add the error log also please?

Comment: I added the error log now

Comment: You removed flexible? Right? Can you add your current full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246280/discussion-between-youcantgetridofmestackoverflow-and-kaushik-chandru).